# Edit Controller in MVC doesn't change data in database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, controller

I am new to ASP.NET MVC and I'm trying to create a small project but I'm stuck in the Edit Controller part.
This is my "real" controller with a function named PostEditViewModel with the queries inside to change the data.

```
public EditViewModel PostEditViewModel(EditViewModel model)
    {
        //var model = new EditViewModel();
        using (var db = new NorthwindEntities())
        {
            var dati = db.Products
                        .Where(p => p.Id == model.Id).Single();
            dati.Id = model.Id;
            dati.Name = model.Name;


            db.SaveChanges();
            return model;
        }

    }
```

And this is my controller, its function is to only validate the model state.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(EditViewModel model)
    {


        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: see this link http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/updating-related-data-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: In what way does this not work?  When you debug this, where does it fail?

Comment: it doesn't save the data I insert in the view to the database

Comment: use `find` instead of single, or attach the entity to the table before you use savechanges

Comment: Where you call POstEditViewModel in your controller??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, the validation didn't make sense at all.

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(EditViewModel model)
    {

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }
        else
        {
            WorkerServices.PostEditViewModel(model);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

Comment: also note that there is no need to use Where. You can simply do: db.Products.Single(x=> x.Id == model.Id);